# Use Flask path string to refer to variables

Tags: python, variables, flask, path, global

I have the following Flask app. It renders a html page with a form for each cell of the dataframe and allows the user to edit the cells and post the form data. The app then updates the dataframe.

'''

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import pandas

app = Flask(__name__)

df_abc = pandas.read_excel('source1.xlsx')

@app.route('/modify/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def modify():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global df_abc
        df_abc = update_df_function() # this function returns an updated df based on the POST data
        return redirect(url_for('modify'))
    
    else:
        table_data = df_abc.to_dict(orient='records')
        return render_template('modify.html', table_data=table_data)
```

'''
However, I would like the following to work:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import pandas

app = Flask(__name__)

df_abc = pandas.read_excel('source1.xlsx')
df_xyz = pandas.read_excel('source2.xlsx')

@app.route('/modify/<name>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def modify(name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global name
        name = update_df_function() # this function returns an updated df based on the POST data
        return redirect(url_for('modify'))
    
    else:
        table_data = name.to_dict(orient='records')
        return render_template('modify.html', table_data=table_data)
```

'''

This app would get the variable name from the Flask path. How can I set the variable names in the modify function (e.g. global df_abc) by using the string < name > from the Flask path? I.e. posting data from [www.site.com/modify/df_abc](http://www.site.com/modify/df_abc) should update df_abc, ./modify/df_xyz should update df_xyz etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using globals() with globals()[name], as shown below, and explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373201

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import pandas

app = Flask(__name__)

df_abc = pandas.read_excel('source1.xlsx')
df_xyz = pandas.read_excel('source2.xlsx')

@app.route('/modify/<name>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def modify(name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        globals()[name] = update_df_function() # this function returns an updated df based on the POST data
        return redirect(url_for('modify'))
    
    else:
        table_data = globals()[name].to_dict(orient='records')
        return render_template('modify.html', table_data=table_data)
```